# How to add request Timeout?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a model and I am fetching records from that model. I want to give to the admin a view where he can set request timeout for fetching data from that model.

But I don't know what to write in controller.

```php
foreach ($grab_xmlfeed as $feed)
{
    $Keyword = str_replace("[KEYWORD]", $keyword, $feed->xml_url);
    $Ip = str_replace("[IP]", $ip, $Keyword);
    $Ua = str_replace("[UA]", $ua, $Ip);
    $Country = str_replace("[COUNTRY]", $country, $Ua);
    $Subid = str_replace("[SUBID]", $subid, $Country);
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to time out: the database request or the controller action?

Comment: the records coming from database see the loop

Comment: time out is related to `php-fpm` which you can change by `php.ini` and if you want to timeout in you application then what  you have done so far ?

Comment: I know but i want to make it dynamic